# Select add additional row for prompt with join

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    concat( a.name, ' -', b.title, '-') AS title
FROM
    tourist_tour as a
    left join ategories as b on a.category=b.id
order by a.name asc
```

I would like to add a row at the start of the results where id would be 0 and title would be "please select a tour".

I have seen answers using

```
Select 0, "select a tour"
UNION ALL
rest of select query
```

but it does not work with my join.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That should work fine. Can you post the full query which does not work and the error message you get?

Comment: Rather strange approach to use database rather than receiving program for this.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Your `ORDER` clause was the main problem I think and the lack of name column in your 2nd `SELECT`. I also added an IFNULL function since you are using a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 0 AS id, "select a tour" AS title
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     a.id,
     concat( a.name, ' -',  IFNULL(b.title,' '), '-') AS title
 FROM
     tourist_tour AS a
 LEFT JOIN categories AS b ON a.category=b.id
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN id ELSE title END
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/310cc3/1/0